# Durandal Transition - Expecting "activeView" to be null but it seems to maintain it's previous state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, transition, durandal

I am learning/working with knockout/durandal and attempting to build my first transition.

I have a row of 3 buttons - let's call them "tab1", "tab2", and "tab3".

Each button has a data-bound click event to a method in my viewmodel - "selectTab1", "selectTab2", and "selectTab3".

When fired, the click events will set an observable property in my viewmodel called "selectedTabModelProperty" which happens to be what the composition is bound to.

So what should happen is, I click a button, the composition realises it's model has been changed, and the transition runs.  And magically, it sort of works like a tab control.

Now I attempt to add a "toggle" feature.  When I click the button of the currently active "tab", I want to hide it.  Essentially, I set the composition model property to "null" which hides the compose div.  Also cool...

The transition is pretty straight forward.  See the code below - it just animates the height of the panels between 0 and their height.

Now for my problem.  In the durandal documentation about transitions, I have found that "context.activeView" is the "old" view/tab, and (context.child) is the "new" view/tab.  If I run my app and select the first tab, unselect the first tab and attempt to select the second tab, there is a delay before the second tab animates in.

I noticed this by inserting large animation durations.  It seems that when I uncheck the tab (and hide the composed div containing tab1) it isn't resetting the "context.activeView" property to null as I would expect.  So what actually happens, is the transition attempts to close the panel that's open (which isn't actually open so it appears to just sit there) before opening the new tab.

So my questions are: Am I mistaken in how the activeView property works?  Is there a different way to dispose of the composed div so it's properly hidden?  Could this actually be an issue with durandal?

**My HTML:**

```
<button data-bind="click: selectTab1">tab1</button>
<button data-bind="click: selectTab2">tab2</button>
<button data-bind="click: selectTab3">tab3</button>

<!-- ko compose: { model: selectedTabModelProperty(), transition: 'slideUpDown' } -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

**My Transition:**

```
var slideUpDown = function (context) {
    return system.defer(function (dfd) {
        function endTransition() {
            dfd.resolve();
        }

        var oldPanel = $(context.activeView);
        var newPanel = $(context.child);

        if (newPanel.length == 0)
        {
            oldPanel.animate({ height: '0px' }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
                oldPanel.css({ height: '', display: 'none' });
                startTransition();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            function startTransition() {
                context.triggerAttach();

                if(newPanel != null && newPanel.length != 0) {
                    var newPanelHeight = newPanel.height();
                    newPanel.css({ height : "0px", display : 'block' });
                    newPanel.animate({ height : newPanelHeight }, 1000, 'swing', function() {
                        newPanel.css({ height : '', display : '' });
                        endTransition();
                    });
                }
            }

            if (oldPanel.length != 0) {
                oldPanel.animate({ height: '0px' }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
                    oldPanel.css({ height: '', display: 'none' });
                    startTransition();
                });
            }
            else
            {
                startTransition();
            }
        }
    }).promise();
};
```

**My ViewModel:**

```
 this.selectedTabModelProperty = ko.observable();

    this.selectTab = function (whichTab) {
        switch (whichTab) {
            case "tab1":
                {
                    this.selectedTabModelProperty(myVM1);
                    break;
                }
            case "tab2":
                {
                    this.selectedTabModelProperty(myVM2);
                    break;
                }
            case "tab3":
                {
                    this.selectedTabModelProperty(myVM3);
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    this.selectedTabModelProperty(null);
                    break;
                }
        }
    };

    this.selectTab1 = function () {
        if(this.selectedTabModelProperty() == myVM1) {
            this.selectedTabModelProperty(null);
            return;
        }
        this.selectTab("tab1");
    };
    this.selectTab2 = function () {
        if(this.selectedTabModelProperty() == myVM2) {
            this.selectedTabModelProperty(null);
            return;
        }   
        this.selectTab("tab2");
    };
    this.selectTab3 = function () {
        if(this.selectedTabModelProperty() == myVM3) {
            this.selectedTabModelProperty(null);
            return;
        }
        this.selectTab("tab3");
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - I'll just drop a dollar in the idiot jar...  Somehow I transposed a "startTransition" with "endTransition".

```
if (newPanel.length == 0)
    {
        oldPanel.animate({ height: '0px' }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
            oldPanel.css({ height: '', display: 'none' });
            **endTransition();**
        });
    }
```